# Is there a way to decrease the height of dropdown picker (react-native-dropdown-picker module)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

[Dropdown Picker Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cOy9.png)

There is no problem in increasing its height but I want to style the container to decrease its height. I have tried changing all the props with style properties but I still can't decrease its height. This is my code below.

```
import {
  ThemeProvider,
  createTheme,
  Header,
  Text,
  SocialIcon,
  Button,
  Divider,
  Overlay,
  SearchBar,
  ListItem,
  Avatar,
} from '@rneui/themed';
import DropDownPicker from 'react-native-dropdown-picker';

// code here
<View>
  <View>
    <Text
      style={{
        fontSize: 14,
        color: COLORS.gray_header2,
      }}>
      Label 2:
    </Text>
    <DropDownPicker
      open={open}
      value={value}
      items={items}
      setOpen={setOpen}
      setValue={setValue}
      setItems={setItems}
      style={styles.dropdown_container}
      textStyle={styles.dropdown_itemstyle}
    />
  </View>
</View>

//code here

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'white',
  },

  dropdown_container: {
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: COLORS.dirty_white,
    borderRadius: 6,
    borderColor: COLORS.gray_filter,
  },
  
  dropdown_itemstyle: {
    color: COLORS.gray_header,
    borderColor: COLORS.gray_filter,
    marginLeft: 10,
  },
});
```

[Dropdown Picker Screenshot with react-devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPstN.png)

Upon using react-devtools module, I have debugged where the height could be changed. Is there any way to decrease its height? (apparently minHeight in devtools)

*Edit*
[Height of the container itself (not the dropdown menu when clicked)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hcpv.png)

Answer (score 6):

If anyone is having the issue of size, minHeight worked for me. See example below.

```
<DropDownPicker
                style={{
                  borderWidth: 1, 
                  borderColor: '#d5d5d9',  
                  backgroundColor: '#eee',
                  borderRadius: 40, 
                  paddingHorizontal: 5,
                  minHeight: 30,   // <---- here               
                }} 
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

As Glen suggested, **maxHeight** is your answer.
[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry if I had not been clear. The height that I was pointing out was the height of the container itself, not when the dropdown menu when it is clicked. I've included another picture just to be clear of what I am talking about

Comment: Try this attribute `props={{ style: { height: 40 } }}`

Comment: just pass these two properties neither the gesture will not handle properly.   
     maxHeight={ 300}
          containerProps={{
            height:  300
          }}

Answer (score 1):

You have to set minHeight and paddingHorizontal in your dropdown_container. In this way you will be able to decrease the height of your dropdown.

```
dropdown_container: {
  width: '100%',
  backgroundColor: COLORS.dirty_white,
  borderRadius: 6,
  borderColor: COLORS.gray_filter,
  paddingHorizontal: 5,
  minHeight: 30,
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi there try adding maxHeight as follow?

maxHeight={200}

Check out the docs from their website: https://hossein-zare.github.io/react-native-dropdown-picker-website/

Comment: I tried to add it but sadly nothing changed in the dropdown picker, it only changed the dropdown menu height

Answer (score 0):

You can check the react-native-dropdown-picker source code in your node_modules folder, in src/themes/dark/index.js or src/themes/light/index.js. The author did a `minHeight:50` for the container height in the stylesheet class which name is style. You can pass your own minHeight through DropDownPicker style property to override it.

I think same as the list Item, just find the correct style property and override it.

Answer (score 0):

Min height is ignored because it looks like it is hardcoded in theme files.
A good exmaple is this MR - https://github.com/hossein-zare/react-native-dropdown-picker/pull/555
So I plan to create custom theme like it is described in docs https://hossein-zare.github.io/react-native-dropdown-picker-website/docs/advanced/themes

Comment: Are you in any way affiliated with the content you recommend? https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion